# Django bulk_create with conditional update

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I've been having a problem on a large database that I need to update by reading data from a csv.

I have a model like this:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ... 
    external_id: models.CharField
    valid_from: models.DateField
    ...
```

After reading and validating the values of a large csv file, I wish to bulk_create new entries, but on the condition that if for an external_id the date of valid_from is newer than in the database, update the field, otherwise skip it.

What is the most efficient way to go about doing this?

My workflow is this:
I read the csv, and pass each line to a validator/data cleaner function which returns a pydantic model instance which matches my django_db model, use the dict representation of the pydantic model to create the django model instance, add it to a list and pass the list to the bulk_create function.

Adding a polling of the db for each row to check whether a value exists and if it does and the date is outdated, then keep going, makes the parser run really slow.
An idea that I had was to make a dict of all the existing external_ids and their respective dates by making a {item.external_id: item.valid_date for item in MyModel.objects.all()} and pass this to the validator function in order to make the check, but this is making my pc crawl and crash for some reason, probably because the db is rather large.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `{item.external_id: item.valid_date for item in MyModel.objects.all()}` instantiates every MyModel object one by one. Try `dict(MyModel.objects.values_list("external_id", "valid_date"))` instead.

Comment: If that is still too slow, maybe you can attempt some raw SQL to utilize the `ON CONFLICT` clause of the `INSERT` command. For example for Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! 
Btw, how can I select this as an answer?